# A quiz taken in a data structure class

Tags: java

Wanted an explanation on the results of question 1.

***1. What is the output of the following method?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer i1=new Integer(1);
    Integer i2=new Integer(1);
    String s1=new String("Today");
    String s2=new String("Today");

    System.out.println(i1==i2);
    System.out.println(s1==s2);
    System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));
    System.out.println(s1!=s2);
    System.out.println( (s1!=s2) || s1.equals(s2));
    System.out.println( (s1==s2) && s1.equals(s2));
    System.out.println( ! (s1.equals(s2)));
}
```

Answer:

```
false
false
true
true
true
false
false
```

---

Comment: What do *you* think it does? If we know that, we can help you a lot better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Integer i1=new Integer(1);
Integer i2=new Integer(1);
String s1=new String("Today");
String s2=new String("Today");

// do i1 and 12 point at the same location in memory?  No - they used "new"
System.out.println(i1==i2);

// do s1 and s2 point at the same location in memory?  No - the used "new"
System.out.println(s1==s2);

// do s1 and s2 contain the same sequence of characters ("Today")?  Yes.
System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));

// do s1 and s2 point at different locations in memory?  Yes - they used "new"
System.out.println(s1!=s2);

// do s1 and s2 point to different locations in memory?  Yes - they used "new".  
// Do not check s1.equals(s2) because the first part of the || was true.
System.out.println( (s1!=s2) || s1.equals(s2));

// do s1 and s2 point at the same location in memory?  No - they used "new".  
// do not check s1.equals(s2) because the first part of the && was false.
System.out.println( (s1==s2) && s1.equals(s2));

// do s1 and s2 not contain the same sequence of characters ("Today")?  No.   
System.out.println( ! (s1.equals(s2)));
```

Answer (score 5):

I think the main point is that `==` compares two object references to see if they refer to the same instance, whereas `equals` compares the values.

For example, s1 and s2 are two different string instances so `==` returns false, but they both contain the value `"Today"` so `equals` returns true.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping in mind that `Integer` and `String` are Objects, the `==` operator compares the memory addresses of those 2 pointers, not the actual Objects themselves. So the first 2 `==` are going to be false because `i1` is not the same Object as `i2`. If the initialization was:

```
Integer i1=new Integer(1);
Integer i2=i1;
```

Then the first println() would have been true.

The `s1.equals(s2)` is the proper way to compare equality in Objects. The String.equals() method will check for string equality, so "Today" and "Today" are equal strings.

The `s1!=s2` is true since s1 and s2 are different Objects, similar to the i1 and i2 issue with `==`

The rest should be pretty straightforward boolean operations.

Answer (score 0):

Which result(s) in particular? Does [this](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=221) help?